# An algebraic space over etale topology is also a fppf-sheaf?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is the Theorem 5.5.2 in M.Olsson's *Algebraic Spaces and Stacks*.
(And Theorem A-4 in *Champs algébriques* by Gérard Laumon, Laurent Moret-Bailly)

Here is the definition of algebraic spaces we used:

> **Definition**. Let $S$ be a scheme. An algebraic space over $S$ is a functor
> $$X:(Sch/S)^{op}\to(Sets)$$such that
> (i) $X$ is a sheaf with respect to the big etale topology;
> (ii) $\Delta_{X/S}:X\to X\times_SX$ is representable;
> (iii) There exists an $S$-scheme $U$ with surjective etale morphism $U\to X$.

**RMK**. In (iii) the 'surjective' means 'surjective representable morphism' instead of sheaf-theoric (or presheaf-theoric) surjective, I think.

---

> **Theorem 5.5.2**. Let $S$ be a scheme, and let $X/S$ be an algebraic space over $S$ with quasi-compact diaganol. Then $X$ is a sheaf with respect to the fppf-topology.

**RMK**. I modified some details in Olsson's proof after seen the original proof in *Champs algébriques*.

*Proof and My Questions*. Let $\overline{X}$ be the sheaf of fppf-topology associated to $X$ with canonical $q:X\to\overline{X}$. We can easy to see $q$ is injective. So we need to show $q$ is surjective(?).

Let $s\in\overline{X}(U)$. By some trick, we may let $U,X$ are all quasi-compact. So we can get a quasi-compact $S$-scheme $X_0$ with surjective and etale morphism $\pi:X_0\to X$. By (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03H6), we can let $X_0$ affine, so by (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06NF), we get $\pi$ is separated.

By some trick similar as in the scheme theory, we can show $\pi$ is quasi-compact (here we used $X$ has a quasi-compact diaganol). Hence $\pi$ is quasi-finite. Hence $\pi$ is **quasi-affine** by using a weak version of Zariski main theorem (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02LR).

Now to show $q$ is surjective, we just need to show that $q\circ\pi$ is surjective, so we need to show $q\circ\pi$ is qausi-affine, etale and surjective.

> [**Here I have some questions:** (a) Why we need to show $q\circ\pi$ qausi-affine here? We may use $\pi$ is quasi-finite, but not $q\circ\pi$?

> (b) What the '**surjective**' here mean? I think the surjectivity of $q$ need be presheaf-theoric surjective! But when we reduced to show that $q\circ\pi$ is surjective, we just used $\pi$ is surjective (as representable morphism). Then by the similar argument (almost trivial) as https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05VM, $\pi$ is etale sheaf-theoric surjective! So we can get $q\circ\pi$ is etale sheaf-theoric surjective. We can't get the presheaf-theoric surjective.]

So just need to show $X_0\times_{\overline{X},s}U$ is qausi-affine, etale and surjective over $U$. By the fppf descent-theory for quasi-affine morphism, we may replace $U$ by an fppf-cover and may therefore assume $s$ lifts to a section $s'\in X(U)$. As $q$ injective (actually monomorphism), we get
$$X_0\times_{\overline{X},s}U\cong X_0\times_{X,s'}U$$ which is the base-change of $\pi$. Hence well done!      Q.E.D.

> [**Here I have some questions:** (c) How do we use the fppf descent-theory for quasi-affine morphism to get the lifts of $s$? Here we have the only quasi-affine morphism is $\pi$ (and its base-change)! But how can we descent along $\pi$ to get $s'$? $X$ is even not a scheme!]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably way too late, but I'm reading the same passage right now and I'll try to record what I figured out.

I'll start with (b). $X$ is an étale sheaf by definition, and so to show schemewise surjectivity, it suffices to show that lifts from $\overline X$ to $X$ exist étale locally, since those lifts necessarily agree on pairwise fibered product by injectivity.

For (c), we are not using fppf descent to get $s'$. $s'$ exists fppf locally because we are considering the sheafification map. What descent theory is doing is that once we know that $X_0\times_{\overline X,s} V$ is a scheme quasi-affine over $V$ whenever $s:V\to \overline X$ factors through $X$, we have an (effective) descent datum for quasi-affine schemes over a fppf covering $V\to U$, and all $U$ admit such a map. This also gives an answer to (a), where the quasi-affineness guarantees the effectiveness of the descent datum.